# Why does Parent.call(this) inside another object works?

Tags: javascript, oop

```
function Parent(){ 
this.name = "parent";
console.log("this gets executed");
}
function Child(){
 Parent.call(this) // doesnt the this here belongs to the child object?
}
var o = new Child();
```

Why does the `this` inside the child object invokes the parent constructor?
Doesnt the `this` refer to the child object?
Please enlighten the noob javascripter thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) not [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

One use of Call is to *chain* constructors (similar to doing `super()` from within child constructor in OOP languages like JAVA). The child constructor is called which in turn creates Parent object from within Child context.

Bind however will set the required `this` for the function.

As suggested an explanation of `this` in javascript can be found [in this blog](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html)
and also in the [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: A reference to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call might be helpful. Also, the `this` keyword can be hard to grasp in JS as its scope is not always clear. This article, http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html, may help explain the confusion.

Comment: Thank you :) the reference to call is already added in my answer. I will update with `this`.

Comment: Thanks it took a little while for me to understand the 'call()' method! Now im like eureka! cheers

Answer (score 1):

`this` is referring the child object only.

Here you are calling `Parent` function in context of `this` (i.e child object).

`Parent.call(this)` is similar to `Parent()` the only difference is context of calling the method.